# C# Find clients then create socket connection

Tags: c#, sockets

I have been experimenting with some code to find other computer's on my network running my app. Firstly I broadcast and listen for those broadcasts. After that I am a little lost on the next step. Once Computer A knows the ip address of Computer B because of the broadcast how do I put Computer B in a state to accept socket connections. Then how does Computer A begin that connection?

Also I have tried doing the broadcasting with Multicast and cannot get that to work. If anyone has extra time could they show that as well.

Starting Listener and Sender:

```
private static void StartServer()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            await StartListeningAsync();
        });

    }

    private static void StartClient()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            await StartSendingAsync();
        });


    }
```

Those inner methods:

```
    private static async Task StartSendingAsync()
    {

        try
        {
            using (UdpClient _broadcaster = new UdpClient())
            {
                var ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("");
                var ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[ipHost.AddressList.Count() - 1];


                IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, PORT);
                var ipAddress = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ipAddr.ToString());
                for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                {
                    _broadcaster.Send(ipAddress, ipAddress.Count(), ip);
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }


    }

    private static async Task StartListeningAsync()
    {


        while (true)
        {
            using (UdpClient _listener = new UdpClient(PORT))
            {
                try
                {
                    IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT);
                    var incoming = await _listener.ReceiveAsync();
                    NewPing(incoming.Buffer, incoming.RemoteEndPoint);
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                }
                catch (SocketException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.TimedOut)
                    {
                        //Time out that's fine
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

What happens when the listener hears a broadcast:

```
private static void NewPing(byte[] incoming, IPEndPoint rem)
    {

        Console.WriteLine($"New ping from {rem.ToString()}, attempting to connect!");

        //What should happen here now that one of the computer's know the other exists?
        //Start some kind of Socket Accepting method?

    }
```

Comment: You have to start computer B listening from an application running on Computer B.  You cannot command from a remote computer to start listening through a socket connection.

Comment: Why not re-couch this question in reverse? Getting clients to accept connections doesn't really fit the description "client"... nor will it play well with firewalls. Why can't the clients discover the server and connect when they find it?

Comment: Because I am making this act as the application can be both a server and a client. So that maybe I want to send a file or receive. I don't know how to start socket connections safely and connect to those computers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a machine to send out a UDP broadcast, and then establish a TCP connection between the two?

I'd perform the following steps:

- **B** is listening for UDP broadcasts
- **A** wants a TCP connection with **B**, so
- **A** starts listening for incoming TCP connections
- **A** sends out a broadcast saying "I'm listening"
- **B** receives the broadcast and attempts to connect to **A**

I've created two sample console applications, one server, one client:

**Server:**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11220));
        listener.Start();
        listener.AcceptSocketAsync().ContinueWith((t) => HandleClient(t.Result));
        Console.WriteLine($"Listening for TCP connections at port 11220...");

        using (UdpClient broadcaster = new UdpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
        {
            broadcaster.EnableBroadcast = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Broadcasting...");
            broadcaster.Send(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 3, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 11221));
        }

        while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Q)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'Q' to quit");
        }
    }

    static void HandleClient(Socket socket)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"TCP connection accepted ({socket.RemoteEndPoint})!");
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (UdpClient client = new UdpClient(11221, AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for broadcast...");
            client.EnableBroadcast = true;
            client.ReceiveAsync().ContinueWith((t) => HandleBroadcast(t.Result)).Wait();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static void HandleBroadcast(UdpReceiveResult result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Received broadcast from {result.RemoteEndPoint}, attempting to connect via TCP");
        Socket socket = new Socket(result.RemoteEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(result.RemoteEndPoint.Address, 11220));
    }
}
```

First start the client, then the server. The data sent in the broadcast is just dummy data, but you could include some information like the TCP port number the server is listening at.

PS. Remember that this is just a proof of concept.

Comment: The hard part is that your step 2. Computer A at the current moment doesn't know Computer B exists. They have to discover each other first. That is what my code does right now.

Comment: @BaileyMiller Exactly, thats why __A__ sends out the broadcast. __A__ simply starts listening for _any_ incoming TCP connection before broadcasting, so __B__ can initiate the connection to __A__ when it receives the broadcast.

Comment: I understand, I am sorry this is hard for me to ask questions about and talk about of all my tech skills networking is by far my worst.

Comment: I'm sorry I'll be travelling in a sec - but you already have the broadcast bit working, and the receiving end of the broadcast has the `IPEndPoint` of the sender. With that information and the tons of TCP client/server examples out there, you should be able to continue.

Comment: I think something that is limiting me is I am working inside of a console application. I am going to move this project to a WPF app for better control over when things are happening.

Comment: @BaileyMiller I've updated my answer, hope it helps a bit

Comment: Seems strange to use C# 6 features (string interpolation) but then to avoid `async/await` in favour of `.Wait()`ing for tasks and the use `Task.ContinueWith`.